# Не срабатывает проверка js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = document.getElementById('text_sms').value;
    var count = text.length;
    $("#counter").html(count);
    $("#count_sms").html(count);
    $("#text_sms").keyup(function() {
        var revText = this.value.length;
        if(revText <= 0){
            $("#counter").html('0');
            $("#count_sms").html('0');
        }else {
            $("#counter").html(revText);
        }

        if(revText <= 70){
            $("#count_sms").html('1');
        }else if(revText > 70) {
            $("#count_sms").html('2');
            }else if(revText > 140){ // здесь не срабатывает проверка кол-во знаков:показывает 142 а кол-во сообщений: 2 и дальше если водить символы  кол-во сообщений: не меняется 
                $("#count_sms").html('3');
            }else if(revText > 210){
                $("#count_sms").html('4');
            }else {
                $("#count_sms").html('0');
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text_sms" rows="4" placeholder="<?php echo $template_name;?>" name="text_sms" type="text"  class="form-control"></textarea>
     <div style="font-size: 14px; position: absolute">кол-во знаков: <span id="counter"></span>&nbsp;  кол-во сообщений: <span id="count_sms"></span></div>
```

Comment: Как вам идея воспользоваться формулой: `Math.floor(revText / 70) + (revText % 70 > 0 ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё отрабатывает правильно, просто в это условие не заходит код, потому что всегда попадает в условие `> 70`, чтобы всё работало лучше идти от большего условия к меньшему и тогда всё будет работать:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = document.getElementById('text_sms').value;
    var count = text.length;
    $("#counter").html(count);
    $("#count_sms").html(count);
    $("#text_sms").keyup(function() {
        var revText = this.value.length;
        if(revText <= 0){
            $("#counter").html('0');
            $("#count_sms").html('0');
        }else {
            $("#counter").html(revText);
        }

        if(revText > 210){
            $("#count_sms").html('4');
        } else if (revText > 140) {
            $("#count_sms").html('3');
        }else if (revText > 70) {
            $("#count_sms").html('2');
        }else if (revText > 0) {
            $("#count_sms").html('1');
        } else {
            $("#count_sms").html('0');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text_sms" rows="4" placeholder="<?php echo $template_name;?>" name="text_sms" type="text"  class="form-control"></textarea>
 <div style="font-size: 14px; position: absolute">кол-во знаков: <span id="counter"></span>&nbsp;  кол-во сообщений: <span id="count_sms"></span></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь совсем не подумал что можно сделать проверку от большего к меньшему.

Comment: @Sender1050 бывает, новички часто на этом попадаются :)

Comment: @Sender1050 не забывайте принимать ответы которые вам подходят